# setvalue command within a loop

Tags: google-apps-script

I am looking through data to find today's date. When the date matches today's date, it will send an email. I am trying to mark it as sent. I have tried multiple different techniques and am having trouble. Notice the last line- I am trying to indicate in the sheet that the mail was sent- so when it is checked again it won't resend.

main issue is using the .setvalue command within a loop

Error: Range not Found

```js
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var row2 = fdata[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(data[i]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd')
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0200', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
    Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      Logger.log("Yes")
      var emailAddress = "myemail@myemail.com";
      var message = "My Message"; 
      var subject = "\[yes!\]";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
      Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
    
    \\ This is the line that I am having failure
      sheet.getRange(i).setValue('Notified');
    }    
  }
```

Comment: Quote the exact error.

Comment: Error: Range not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a coordinate address, not just row but row and column.

```
sheet.getRange(1,i).setValue("Sent")
```

Comment: Thanks I was able to get this to work- just need to switch rows & cols- Thanks!       sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue("Sent")